# How do I know my Eevee is ready to evolve into Umbreon?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I know his friendship needs to be over the 220 mark but what reactions will I get from him when he's ready?

Comment: Do you mean reactions from talking to him as a walking Pokémon in HGSS?  If so, you should add the `pokemon-hgss` tag, as DPPt don't have walking Pokémon.  If that's not what you meant, what is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a friendship checker in [Goldenrod City](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Goldenrod_City#Friendship_checker), in a house near the cycle shop. The ratings that she will say are:

> - **250-255** - "It looks really happy! It must love you a lot."
> - **200-249** - "I get the feeling that it really trusts you."
> - **150-199** - "It's friendly toward you. It looks sort of happy."
> - **100-149** - "It's quite cute."
> - **50-99** -  "You should treat it better. It's not used to you."
> - **0-49** - "It doesn't seem to like you at all. It looks mean."

According to [this source](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/47551/how-much-happiness-does-an-eevee-require-evolve-into-umbreon), the exact amount of friendship you'll need for Eevee to evolve into Umbreon is 220. Just remember to level it up at night time once you reach this amount of friendship!

---

Now I can't find an exact source of all the walking-pokemon interactions and what they represent in terms of happiness, although from memory once the speech bubbles start to show love hearts, it means it's generally high friendship. I *think* when your Pokemon dances for joy or hugs you, that represents the highest tier of friendship.

You can read more about interacting with the walking Pokemon [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Walking_Pok%C3%A9mon#Pok.C3.A9mon_HeartGold_and_SoulSilver)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In Pokemon Black/White you can go to a girl in the pokemon Fan Club in [Icirrus City](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Icirrus_City). She will tell you how much your pokemon likes you.</strike>

If you want to know how to get friendship fast take a look at the Bulbagarden [friendship page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship)

Comment: Are you aware the question is about fourth gen? bw is fifth gen.

Comment: Sorry but i read fifth my bad (looks quite the same).